# Read excel file with read only option in R

Tags: r

I have an excel file with password protection. But I have the access to the read only file for that file.

Is there a way I can import all the data into a data frame in R using the read only option.

Thanks & Regards,
R

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#install.packages("XLConnect")

library(XLConnect)

workbook <- loadWorkbook("data.xlsx", password = "my_passwoard")

df <- readWorksheet(workbook, "sheet1")
```